# Implement an HTML page into a quartz composition

Tags: quartz-composer

I would like to show a web page through a quartz composition, is this possible? The HTML must be able to call and use other external files like a JS.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The [CoGeWebKit](http://code.google.com/p/cogewebkit/) plugin may be helpful.

From its documentation:

> CoGeWebKit is a Quartz Composer plugin that leverages WebKit to allow offscreen rendering of web technologies including interactive Flash and Java content. Control mouse input, browse normally and post process rendered web pages in Quartz Composer.